# Search functionality not working at the Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

I've noticed the search functionality at the Help Center does not seem to be working, and it seems to be a Stack Exchange - wide issue.  Is it just my imagination?  I tried searching for terms like "question", "answer" and so on without any luck.

Comment: It's not your imagination--only. I do have the same imagination :-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that; help center search should be working again now.

Comment: Ghost is haunting us again. The search in help center not working again and the issue is network wide. Should I post a separate question on [meta.se]?